# Why do the leaf margin and a few of leaf blade of my peach trees turn brown and red?

Tags: diagnosis, peaches

The peach trees are about two years old and young leaf color turns as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Please give any and all information you are able to recount; fertilizer? the  zone you live in, the microclimate, what is happening at the base of your trees? Were these Balled and Burlapped or were they bare root when they were planted two years ago? Do you know the species/variety of your trees?  Please send a picture of the entire tree and the trunk/soil.  Was this the same as last year in the spring?  Do you know your soil pH?  Did you plant these trees or did someone else plant these trees?  How do you manage water?  I do not see browned edges in this one picture.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to a lot of plants when bright sunny days come suddenly. Make sure you water the trees as they are already stressed by the long bright days and prevent them suffering from drought also, otherwise some of the leaves might fall.